# TP-LINK Archer T4U V2 Arch Linux Install

Tags: drivers, installation, arch-linux

So I just purchased the TP-LINK Archer T4U V2 and I'm trying to set it up with my arch linux OS. The manual said to download the driver from the TP-LINK website, which I have done. It gave me a zip file. I've extracted that and now I'm unsure of what to do to install it. The CD that came with the adapter didn't give me further instructions on what to do. I've tried searching the web and can't find a solution. Inside the folder that was extracted is a few folders and a Makefile file. Do I have to do something with the Makefile in the terminal?

EDIT:

I downloaded from the AUR rtl8812au-dkms-git. I created the package. But when I try to install it via sudo pacman -U *xz I get an error No kernel 4.15.3-2-ARCH headers. You must install them to use DKMS!

Then from the zip file I downloaded from TP-LINK I did sudo make and I get this error: No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop. Above that I get a bunch of -Who-unused. Not sure if they're errors or not. In a few minutes I'll copy and paste the whole result in the terminal.

```
[vinny@archlinux2017 8812au]$ sudo make
[sudo] password for vinny: 
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
----- extra_cflags= -O1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -I/include -I/platform -DCONFIG_RTL8812A -DCONFIG_MP_INCLUDED -DCONFIG_POWER_SAVING -DCONFIG_TRAFFIC_PROTECT -DCONFIG_LOAD_PHY_PARA_FROM_FILE -DREALTEK_CONFIG_PATH="" -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_EN=0 -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_MODE=0 -DCONFIG_BR_EXT '-DCONFIG_BR_EXT_BRNAME=br0' -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.3-2-ARCH/build M=/home/vinny/Downloads/8812au  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.3-2-ARCH/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.3-2-ARCH/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1636: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: did you check if arch linux already recognizes the device? ... did you plug it in and try to connect to wifi?

Comment: It's not recognizing it at all. When I use ip link in the terminal, all I get is the loopback, and my ehternet. Nothing else is being shown. I am using Kernel 4.15 so maybe it's not supported yet? I'm going to edit my post that says what I've managed to do so far and it's not working yet.

Comment: do you have a current linux-headers installed?

Comment: I’m gonna guess I don’t have them. How can I check?

Comment: please install `linux-headers` (`pacman -Syyu linux-headers`) to check if its installed `pacman -Q linux-headers` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. I was able to install from the AUR the chipset and now I have internet. :)